Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type '' whenever I try to add migration
The problem occurs whenever I try to add migration with any kind of DbSet. When I leave all of the dbsets commented the ApplicationDbContext instance exists. I have searched throughout all similar cases and even chatgpt didnt help me. Feel free to edit repo https://github.com/PatrykSypula/test
Here is the error from the -verbose.
Using assembly 'ASPNET_EF'.
Using startup assembly 'ASPNET_EF'.
Using application base 'C:\Users\patry\source\repos\ASPNET_EntityFramework\ASPNET_EF\bin\Debug\net8.0'.
Using working directory 'C:\Users\patry\source\repos\ASPNET_EntityFramework\ASPNET_EF'.
Using root namespace 'ASPNET_EF'.
Using project directory 'C:\Users\patry\source\repos\ASPNET_EntityFramework\ASPNET_EF\'.
Remaining arguments: .
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Found IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementation 'ApplicationDbContextFactory'.
Found DbContext 'ApplicationDbContext'.
Finding application service provider in assembly 'ASPNET_EF'...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
Using environment 'Development'.
Using application service provider from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Using DbContext factory 'ApplicationDbContextFactory'.
Using context 'ApplicationDbContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingSource.FindCollectionMapping(RelationalTypeMappingInfo info, Type modelType, Type providerType, CoreTypeMapping elementMapping)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingSource.<>c.<FindMappingWithConversion>b__8_0(ValueTuple`4 k, RelationalTypeMappingSource self)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd[TArg](TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg factoryArgument)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingSource.FindMappingWithConversion(RelationalTypeMappingInfo mappingInfo, Type providerClrType, ValueConverter customConverter)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingSource.FindMappingWithConversion(RelationalTypeMappingInfo mappingInfo, IReadOnlyList`1 principals)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingSource.FindMapping(MemberInfo member)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.MemberClassifier.IsCandidatePrimitiveProperty(MemberInfo memberInfo, IConventionModel model, CoreTypeMapping& typeMapping)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.PropertyDiscoveryConvention.Process(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.PropertyDiscoveryConvention.ProcessEntityTypeAdded(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnEntityTypeAdded(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnEntityTypeAddedNode.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.DelayedConventionScope.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelInitialized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelInitialized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model..ctor(ConventionSet conventions, ModelDependencies modelDependencies, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder..ctor(ConventionSet conventions, ModelDependencies modelDependencies, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelConfigurationBuilder.CreateModelBuilder(ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, ModelCreationDependencies modelCreationDependencies, Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__8_4(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService(IInfrastructure`1 accessor, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)

ApplicationDbContext:
using ASPNET_EF.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ASPNET_EF.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {
        }
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Dictionaries> Dictionaries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Words> Words { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Statistics> Statistics { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubscribedDictionary> SubscribedDictionary { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Dictionaries>(cs =>
            {
                cs.HasMany(d => d.Words)
                    .WithOne(w => w.Dictionary)
                    .HasForeignKey(w => w.DictionaryId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

                cs.HasMany(d => d.Statistics)
                    .WithOne(s => s.Dictionary)
                    .HasForeignKey(s => s.DictionaryId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

                cs.HasMany(d => d.SubscribedDictionaries)
                    .WithOne(sc => sc.Dictionary)
                    .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.DictionaryId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

                cs.HasOne(d => d.DictionaryLevelValues)
                    .WithMany(dlv => dlv.Dictionaries)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.DictionaryLevelId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
            });
        }
    }
}

Program.cs
using ASPNET_EF.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DeveloperConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});

app.Run();

Also chatgpt gave me ApplicationDbContextFactory however it doesnt seem to help:
using ASPNET_EF.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

            return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}

Models:
public class Dictionaries
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
    public string DictionaryName { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public int DictionaryLevelId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
    public string DictionaryDescription { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public int IsDefaultDictionary { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public string IsPublic {  get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(400)")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public DictionaryLevelValues DictionaryLevelValues { get; set; }
    public List<SubscribedDictionary> SubscribedDictionaries { get; set; } = new List<SubscribedDictionary>();
    public List<Words> Words { get; set; } = new List<Words>();
    public List<Statistics> Statistics { get; set; } = new List<Statistics>();
}

public class DictionaryLevelValues
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(2)")]
    public string DictionaryLevel { get; set; }

    public List<Dictionaries> Dictionaries { get; set; } = new List<Dictionaries>();

}

public class Statistics
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
    public DateTime SessionDate { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public int GoodAnswers { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public int AllAnswers { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(10)")]
    public string Percentage { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public int DictionaryId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(400)")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public Dictionaries Dictionary { get; set; }
}

public class SubscribedDictionary
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(400)")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public int DictionaryId { get; set; }

    public Dictionaries Dictionary { get; set; }

}

public class Words
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
    public string WordPolish { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
    public string WordTranslated { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public int DictionaryId { get; set; }

    public Dictionaries Dictionary { get; set; }
}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. A link to the repo is helpful for context, but an SO question should be as self-contained as possible.

This question is asked here all the time. Have you followed the link? There are three ways to solve the problem.
